# Cannot display Google map with a marker based on a zip code

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display Google map with a marker based on a zip code. I've converted the zip code on the **lat** and **lng** coordinates, but the problem is that the map is not displayed at all.

Here's how I am attempting to do that:

```
  function initialize() {
    var lat = '';
    var lng = '';
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': 94301}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), myOptions);
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
        alert('111');
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 }
```

Not even the **alert('111')** is appeared.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check javascript console that there are no errors? if none of those alerts are shown I suspect that there is a problem before reaching those lines.

Comment: No errors in console, no alerts. I guess there's something wrong with the markers, a simple map does work well, cannot find the bug though.

Comment: If you remove marker creation and console.log those lat, lng it works?

Comment: How are you loading in the maps API?

Comment: Hey, what if you remove map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location); line, its useless because you already set center of the map at mapOptions ?

Comment: Guys, it's a stupid bug -- the second line from the bottom should be after the last bracket... Damn it!

Comment: @user984621 - ah you spotted it about the same time as I posted my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here, you're calling the initialize function **within** the initialize function!

```
function initialize() {
    ...
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}
```

Move that last line outwith that function, and you'll start seeing some results I think.

```
function initialize() {
    ...
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

2 issues:

1. your listener on the onload event is inside the initialize function, so it never calls initialize
2. when I fix that I get a javascript error

   ```
    Uncaught InvalidValueError: in property address: not a string
   ```
3. then:

   ```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: myOptions is not defined
   ```

So:

```
     function initialize() {
        var lat = '';
        var lng = '';
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': "94301"}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            var mapOptions = {
              zoom: 8,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), mapOptions);
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            alert('111');
          } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
          }
        });

     }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```